# Search the document using SharePoint search API not include content

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search

I do not want my search API to search for the content.

```
_api/search/query?queryTemplate='"tax" '&selectproperties='RefinableString00'&refinementfilters='and (RefinableString107:("US%20Tax"),ListId:("-6e1f-42a9-ab38-f37912c8c303"),RefinableString104:("test"))'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=5000&sortlist='[docid]:ascending'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following sample to exclude content:

```
https://your-sharepoint-site/_api/search/query?
    sourceid='your_source_id'&
    rowlimit='number_of_results'&
    selectproperties='Property1,Property2'&
    querytext='your_search_query'&
    enablequeryrules=false&
    enablephonetic=false&
    trimduplicates=false
```